# How to create dialogflow conversation to make a price estimation

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

My agent’s goal is to ask  6 questions to make a price estimation of 2 different products.
It asks the 1st question: ‘do you want to make a price estimation for product1 or product2 ?’
And then, it asks 5 questions about the product’s characteristics (i.e. the product’s age, size…) to finally display the price estimation.
All flow made on Dialogflow UI with an inline editor for the fulfillment to calculate and then save data on Firebase DB.

My question -> Is it better to create :

1/ **Create only 2 intents** : product1 and product2 ? Then in those intents, ask the others 5 questions in ‘action and parameters’ section by filling parameters, entities and values.

2/ **Create 6 differents intents** for the 6 questions, with parameter value for each ones.

On my side :

- I have tested the 1/, I’m able to retrieve all data on my Firebase DB but **my 2 products have similar entities and parameters values** (‘size’ for example) and my agent make errors’ flow to the wrong intent.
- I have tested the 2/ (I think it’s the better way because all intents are more efficient) I’m able to make the good flow. But at the last question, I don’t know **how to retrieve previous parameters values** to make the price estimation.

Thanks a lot for the help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Intents are designed to capture what the user is saying - not necessarily the logic behind how you intend to handle that. While you can use things like Contexts to keep track of state, it is sometimes better to handle that with your logic. (See [Thinking for Voice: Design Conversations not Logic](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/thinking-for-voice-design-conversations-not-logic-7c60869451f1))

You should be storing anything you wish to remember between Intents in the parameters of a long-lived [Context](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts).

Comment: Thx, you have confirmed my believe. I made it with differents intents and retrieve all parameters to save them on Firebase RealTime Database.

Comment: Storing it in the Real-time database also makes sense, as long as you're associating the information with the same user or session. If my answer has helped, upvoting and/or accepting it is always appreciated.